# Wordpress: Change post_status of a Taxonomy to Draft

Tags: database, wordpress, phpmyadmin

Is it possible to convert post status of a taxonomy to draft with phpMyAdmin?

Post-status is stored in `wp_posts` while taxonomy `term_id` is stored `wp_term_taxonomy`.

The first part is something as:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_status=’draft’ WHERE
```

But I have no idea who to write the second part.

Hope someone can help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

WordPress taxonomies don't have any status and so you cannot keep those in draft or trash.

Comment: so, is it possible for tags?

Comment: No! Only post types can have the status.